# Expand rows in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Name Description Count
a     This is a   3
b     This is b   2
c     This is c   1
```

I want to modify this dataframe as follows:

```
Name Description Count
a     This is a   1
a     This is a   1
a     This is a   1
b     This is b   1
b     This is b   1
c     This is c   1
```

Basically, duplicate every row by the value of a particular column.

Am new to python and not familiar with libraries yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `reindex` with `repeat`

```
df=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.Count)).assign(Count=1)
```